# cual es la mejor manera para no utilizar muchos if?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tengo un combo que se llena con una lista, la cual tiene 29 elementos, y cada elemento al seleccionarlo en el combo despliega mas campos, entonces
tengo las siguientes condiciones, lo que hace es validar que documento seleccionaste y renderiza los input correspondientes a ese documento seleccionado, pero uso muchos if, y siento que no es  buena practica, como puedo mejorarlo o que puedo implementar?

```
//Dependiendo el tipo de docuemnto de nacionalidad, se mostraran campos
public void obtenerDocumentosNacionalidad() {

    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 1) {
        muestraDetalleDocuemnto = true;

    } else {
        muestraDetalleDocuemnto = false;
    }
    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 2) {
        muestraDetalleActa = true;

    } else {
        muestraDetalleActa = false;
    }
    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 3) {
        muestraDetalleDeclaratoria = true;

    } else {
        muestraDetalleDeclaratoria = false;
    }
    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 4) {
        muestraDetalleCertificado = true;

    } else {
        muestraDetalleCertificado = false;
    }
    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 5) {
        muestraDetalleCedula = true;

    } else {
        muestraDetalleCedula = false;
    }
    if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio() == 6) {
        muestraCertifiMatricula = true;

    } else {
        muestraCertifiMatricula = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: define un array con los tipos y el indice de `getIdSysTipoProbatorio` te dira la accion que necesitas

Comment: Podrías usar un `switch - case`  y todos los valores por defecto en `false`, cuando el `case` coincide, cambias el valor a `true`

Comment: gracias! @JackNavaRow

Comment: gracias @FedericoMadoery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como las variables son booleanas, hacer una comprobación es innecesario:

```
public void obtenerDocumentosNacionalidad() {
    int valor=systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio();

    muestraDetalleDocumento=(valor==1);
    muestraDetalleActa=(valor==2);
    muestraDetalleDeclaratoria=(valor==3);
    muestraDetalleCertificado=(valor==4);
    muestraDetalleCedula=(valor==5);
    muestraCertifiMatricula=(valor==6);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso en lugar de leer dentro del método el valor de `systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio()`, puedes enviarlo como parametro:

```
obtenerDocumentosNacionalidad(systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio());
```

y tu método quedaría de esta forma, para asignar los valores correctos en las variables:

```
public void obtenerDocumentosNacionalidad(int tipo) {
    muestraDetalleDocumento = (tipo==1);
    muestraDetalleActa = (tipo==2);
    muestraDetalleDeclaratoria = (tipo==3);
    muestraDetalleCertificado = (tipo==4);
    muestraDetalleCedula = (tipo==5);
    muestraCertifiMatricula = (tipo==6);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código "muestraDetalleDocumento" es verdadero siempre que "systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio()" sea un entero entre 1 y 6 y es falso en cualquier otro caso. Creo que lo que te conviene es algo asi:

```
if (systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio()>= 1 && systiposprobatorios.getIdSysTipoProbatorio()<=6) {
        muestraDetalleDocumento = true;  }
else
{  muestraDetalleDocumento = false;  }
```

O sea, si la función condicional lee un numero entre 1 y 6 "muestraDetalleDocumento" sera verdadera, caso contrario sera falsa.